# How to load a load with ajax without includ all php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

i have probleme when i load a page with.laod() or $.ajax()
it load only the content like static page

at page1.php i have function getStats() as php and i have a `<div id="loadpage">`

and at page2.php i when use the getStats() and page2.php is load in the `<div id="loadpage">`

so i have include all the file i need at page2.php but it start become too slow

so i tried load page with a include and when any checkbox checked it will load the content again like

```
$("#loadpage").text("<?php include "page2.php"?>");
```

but you can imagine what i get when my page2.php have a table with 300 line data

so i give up this solution

and my plan is every time i check a checkbox it will reset my table

```
$func=getStats($_POST['statut']);
<div id="loadpage">
echo "$func";
</div>
```

actuel code : // it load but really slow

[page1.php]

```
<div id="loadpage">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){  
    $("#loadpage").load("views/suivicommande2View.php",{"statut" : "","page":"page2.php"});


    $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(){
      var statut = [];
      $.each($(".ckb:checked"), function(){
        statut.push($(this).val());
      });

      console.log(statut);
      var urgent = $("input[name='Urgent']").val();
      console.log(urgent);

      $("#loadpage").load("views/page2.php",{"statut" : statut,"page":"suivicommande2View.php"});
    });

  });

</script>
```

[page2.php]

```
<?php include "function.php" ?>
<table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered display" style="width:100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
         <th> some th here</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody >
      <?php
        $data=getStats($_REQUEST['statut']); //getStats function is in function.php
        //getStats([statut]){ return data } 
        // var_dump($historiques);
        foreach ($data as $oneData) {
        //showing all my data as table
        }
      </tbody>
</table>
```

[function.php]

```
function getStats($condition = null,$date=null,$type=null,$hide_col=false){
  //setting default val
  if($condition == null)$condition = null;
  if($data == null)$date="DESC";
  if($type == null) $type=null;
  if($hide_col==0)$hide_col=" AND hide_col IS NULL";else {
    $hide_col="";
  }

  $where=where($condition);
  $where2=where2($type);
  if(!$date === null){
    $ordre =" ORDER BY `wor7576_historique_commandes`.id_commande".$date;
  }else {
    $date ="";
  }

  $req="SELECT distinct * FROM `wor7576_historique_commandes` where ".$where2." AND ".$where."  ".$hide_col." ".$ordre;

  // echo $req ; // show query req


  $db=DBConnect();
  $mysqli_request = mysqli_query($db, $req);

  $res=array();
  $result_request = mysqli_fetch_all($mysqli_request, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

  return $result_request;
}

function where($condition){
  if(!count($condition)==0){
    $where =" ( ";
    for ($i=0; $i < count($condition); $i++) {
      $where= $where." statut = ".$condition[$i];
      if( $i ==(count($condition)-1) ){
      }else{
        $where= $where ." OR ";
      }
    }
    $where =$where .")";
  }else {
    $where =" (statut = statut) ";
  }
  return $where;

}

function where2($type){
  if(!count($type)==0){
    $where2 =" ( ";
    for ($i=0; $i < count($type); $i++) {
      $where2 = $where2." type = '".$type[$i];
      if( $i ==(count($type)-1) ){
      }else{
        $where2 = $where2 ."' OR '";
      }
    }
    $where2 = $where2 ."')";
  }else {
    $where2 ="(type = type)";
  }

  return $where2;
}
```

i'm just learning the jq and ajax at internet like 1 week 
i'm not sure im using the .load or ajax right way..

Comment: i can't see any function called "check()" in your code. How is it relevant? And how slow is "too slow". How long is it taking, exactly? Loading 300 rows shouldn't take _that_ long, unless your query is complicated. Show us what getStats() is doing, please. It seems you want to change which data is displayed based on which checkboxes are checked, so I think you will need to load _something_ from the server, but maybe you can get it to just load parts that you haven't already loaded. Exactly how you might do that will depend somewhat on how getStats() is working.

Comment: @ADyson i have upload my function
well i have the same code without ajax full php with button click valid when it load the page it take round 10-30 ms

Comment: with the jq autoload the frist load it take round like 2-3 second for show up
console network->
blocked 21 ms , connect 20 ms , wait 1804ms , received 675 ms , Total 2520ms ............(rip 5 minute i must write new comment)

Comment: ok so you need to narrow it down and find out how much of the time is being used by the SQL. Get your page to output the SQL being generated, and then run that separately in MySQL workbench, and note how long it takes. This will help you to know if the issue is that you need to optimise your query, or some other part of your code, or perhaps whether it's just an issue of slow network

Comment: It seems to be though, that each extra checked box adds another OR clause to your query...is that correct? If so then you could actually, when a box is checked, simply ask the server to fetch _only_ the data which relates to that checkbox directly, and then you can append it to the end of the table. If the user un-checks the box, you can just use JavaScript to remove the rows which relate to that checkbox from the HTML (but first you'd probably need to add some property to the HTML table row element so you know which ones belong to which checkbox)

Comment: Or, another alternative potentially is: if the dataset is not too large, then just download _all_ the data at the start when the page loads. And then, just use client-side JavaScript code to hide and show bits of the table depending on the selected boxes. That removes the need for repeated AJAX calls entirely. But if the table gets too big (beyond a few hundred rows probably), you might find that starts to be slow too. It depends on your circumstances.

Comment: @ADyson well the SQL is correct for the old version the same page same resultat and the same function it just load in 30 ms, and download the data isnt my chose bcs once i end this i will make it refresh every 10 s something like syncro ------- last question : ajax use more for load the data or full page ?  or a controller ?

Comment: None of that really answers anything I asked. But...you want to make it update every 10 seconds as well as when the user changes the selection? Why? Does the database data change so frequently? In such a frequent update scenario you might be better off using Websockets instead of AJAX.

Comment: P.s. Ajax is most often used to download small amounts of data (e.g. in JSON format) which are then processed by the JavaScript code, or bits of HTML ready to be inserted into the page - like you're doing now. You never load a whole  page with Ajax, that makes no sense. And a controller is a concept in the MVC design pattern describing a collection of endpoints on the server which can be called by a HTTP request (either an Ajax request or any other HTTP request). A controller is not an alternative to Ajax, as you seem to be implying, it's a different part of the system.

Comment: @ADyson ho dam this why i feel i using at the wrong way ty for the answer